# Any good Demo Recording tool?

Tags: user-interface, demo, voice-recording, video-recording

Looking for a tool that allows to record a user session to be used to create a video demo.
Functionalities needed:
 - zoom-in / zoom-out
 - field highlights
 - spotlights
 - narrative voice recording
 - video editing (cut, insert titles or slides, ...)
 - ...

Open source alternatives are preferred, although commercial ones are ok (I'd love to do Apple-style videos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm).  It's not free, but it has great functionality and publishing options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at some of the tools mentioned on this page for creating some demo videos of features on my site that I'll be posting to YouTube.com.

http://altawebworks.com/articles/internet-marketing/make-your-own-video-demo

Also, I'm checking out some tools mentioned here that are free:

http://mashable.com/2008/02/21/screencasting-video-tutorials/